# ¿Enviar notificación entre dispositivos con Firebase?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

Estoy intentando que una aplicación que esté cerrada haga saltar una notificación cuando modifique la base de datos desde otro dispositivo. Actualmente uso la clase Service y busco modificaciones en las listas de mi base de datos de Realtime Database de Firebase.

```
public class Servicio extends Service {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference referenciaDB = database.getReference("General/Citas/"+Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()));
    List<Cita> datosFirebase = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Cita> datosFirebaseCopia = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        referenciaDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               if (datosFirebase.isEmpty()){
                   // Rellenamos array de coches
                   for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                       Cita cita = objSnapshot.getValue(Cita.class);
                       datosFirebase.add(cita);
                   }
               }
                //Si el clon esta vacio (Obviamente estara vacio la primera vez) haz una copia de lo primero que ha cogido de la base de datos.
               if (datosFirebaseCopia.isEmpty()){
                   datosFirebaseCopia = datosFirebase;
               }
                //Si ambas son iguales, nada ha cambiado ( La primera vez obviamente nada ha cambiado)
                if (!datosFirebase.equals(datosFirebaseCopia)) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "Hey hola, ¿Que has hecho? , vengo de revisar la base de datos ¿Y que crees? , no hay nada nuevo... sin cambios, no cambia, no madura,no crece la" +
                            "base de datos.");
                }//Pero si la segunda vez que cheque si son iguales y no lo son, es que la base de datos ha cambiado
                else {
                    //Ahora si, echame la notificaciooon!
                    //Notificación , nada sorprendente.
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                        // Configure the notification channel.
                        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                    }


                    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplication(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

                    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo1)
                            .setTicker("Hearty365")
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setContentTitle("Default notification")
                            .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
                            .setContentInfo("Info");

                    notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());

                    datosFirebaseCopia = datosFirebase;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w("TEST", "No funciono mi idea >.<", error.toException());
            }
        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Envío una intención(Intent) desde mi Actividad principal para iniciar la clase. Y esta clase esta declarada en el manifests

```
<service
        android:name=".Utilidades.Servicio"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

No se si estoy cometiendo algún error conceptual y debo realizar esta tarea de otra forma. Se agradece cualquier ayuda, saludos.

Comment: ¿Para qué usas un servicio, si Firebase tiene su propio modo de notificar mensajes?  [Mira toda la documentación aquí y código de ejemplo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) (está en castellano).

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, lo intentaba hacer sin implementar FCM ya que tengo que solicitar los token de usuario y enviar específicamente la notificación a ese usuario. Pero no me queda otra por lo que veo. ¿Alguna forma de hacerlo sin FCM?